# how to specify the '<pathlist>' while using 'keytool -importcert ... -providerpath <pathlist>...'

Tags: java, keytool

while using command below:

`keytool -importcert -v -trustcacerts -alias mycert -file cacert.pem \
-keystore mycert.bks -storetype BKS \
-providerpath /path/to/prov-1.53.0.0.jar \ 
-providerclass org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
-storepass blahblah`

it generate this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/spongycastle/util/Strings
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.spongycastle.util.Strings
>   ...

so I figured I also need to pass the `/path/to/core-1.53.0.0.jar` to the `-providerpath`

`keytool -importcert -help` shows `-providerpath <pathlist>`, I don't know whether it implicates I can attach a list-like param to it or not, and if so which is the right way to do it.(i have tried using space as delimiter like the bash array, comma like the c array, also the colon)

Comment: My guess is that it would be a colon delimited list similar to the -cp argument for the java command but I don't have a handy environment for testing it.

Comment: @Pace OMG, it works, i don't know why i just haven't thought about that before. Thanks man!

Comment: Great, added that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-providerpath` argument can take a colon delimited list of jars, similar to the `-cp` or `-classpath` argument to the java command.